# MYSQL Database Structure for 2-round Events

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'd like to create a database to store information about events with the following details for each record:

```
Event, Player 1 name, Player 2 name, Final score

Round 1:
Date, location, Important detail 1, Important detail 2

Round 2:
Date, location, Important detail 1, Important detail 2
```

Could someone tell me how this would translate to a mySQL database please? I mean by that a suitable database name, whether I need one or multiple tables, what fields I need to create.

I might be over-complicating things in my mind, but I'm wondering if there are "layers" in a database or whether I would just have individual fields such as `round1 date`, `round1 location`, ...., `round2 date` etc, as opposed to something like `event1 rounds` with sub tables for each round.

Comment: "How much do you plan to pay?" This question is too broad for this site, also you may have something in your mind, you may did some research, but you've failed to share it with us. StackOverflow is not a code generator service. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) With which part do you have problems?

Answer (score 0):

When naming database it is normally project or company name.
in this case your game name

for keeping data you need to consider normalization rules. from that you can think how many tables and which table data should go.
in this case one event has multiple rounds

when naming tables i prefer prefixing parent so things can be find easily.

So putting altogether

Database name: **company/game name**

**event**
event_id(unique),   player 1,   player 2,   final score ,

**event_round**
event_id,   round_id(unique),   round number,   date,   location,

**event_round_important**
round_id,   important_data,